# Strange SQL result order by date, count(date)

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-order-by

I'm atm seeing a strange behaviour in a sql request.

My table pointLog:

`#  Column  Type

1   date    timestamp 
2   uid     varchar(30)

3   ssid    varchar(40)

4   reason  varchar(50)

5   points  int(5)          No  None`

The statement:

```
SELECT date, count(date) as anzahl FROM pointLog WHERE uid = 1 order by date desc
```

returns following result

```
    date                anzahl
2012-09-01 12:21:16     14
```

But the statement:

```
SELECT date FROM pointLog WHERE uid = 1 order by date desc
```

Returns

```
2012-09-02 12:44:08
```

as first result.

**So my question**: why I'm not receiving the `2012-09-02` as first result in the first statement which includes a count ??

Thanks a lot!

**edit** 
The count as anzahl is atm only used to verify that there are more than 0 entries in this example. I know its should be tested in the programm.

But my main problem is, that I can't explain, why I'm getting 2 different dates when it's sorted by the same (date). So the only difference is the count attribute. But that shouldn't normally change the sorting?

**FINAL*** The solution

```
SELECT MAX(date) AS maxdate, COUNT(date) AS anzahl FROM pointLog WHERE uid = 1
```

Comment: You should get an error message that you can't select the date column because you are not grouping by it. Are you sure you are posting the exact thing you are doing?

Comment: Yes the statement is exactly what I'm using.

Comment: PERFECT! Thats the solution, which is much better than the subquery totally ignored the MAX solution

Comment: @erikkallen - That's not true in MySql.  If you select a field that is not in the GROUP BY, and is not an aggregate, a randomly chosen (non deterministic) value is returned.  This allow you to group by a primary key and select value from that table - all the values in the group are the same, so the non-deterministic behaviour isn't a problem.  But it is 'inappropriate' to use it as in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @prosfilaes answered, your query does not return deterministic results, the `date` returned in an arbitrary one.

If you want the latest date and the count, you can use:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(date) AS maxdate, 
    COUNT(date) AS anzahl 
FROM 
    pointLog 
WHERE 
    uid = 1 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting one results: a count of the dates, preceded by an arbitrary date. The ORDER BY statement is then ordering that, which is a no-op because there's only one line of output.

Comment: OK so the result date which is returned is not deterministic? How can i get the latest entry of the date with a count of total entries over all dates in the database? Do i have to do 2 requests for that or can i combine both in one?

Answer (score 0):

You need a GROUP BY in your SQL statement, otherwise the COUNT() will not give separate totals for each date.